# OpenGL can't send variables from vertex shader to fragment shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm pretty new to OpenGL and just started with a basic program that has a vertex shader and a fragment shader. Everything worked until I tried to send data from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. I use `out` in the vertex shader and `in` in the fragment shader.

Here are the shaders.

The Vertex:

```
#version 120
varying vec4 ourColor;
attribute vec3 position;

void main()
{
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
ourColor = vec4(1.0,0.1,0.2,0.5);
}
```

And the Fragment:

```
#version 120 
varying vec4 ourColor;

void main()
{
gl_FragColor = ourColor;
}
```

The error is:

> Fragment Shader contains a user varying but is linked without a vertex shader.

I tried using the `flat` keyword, and the `varying` keyword, same result. Also I've tried changing the version and then using `in` and `out`, same error.

Here is the Shader code (it's in a shader class, this is Shader.cpp):

```
     Shader::Shader(const std::string & fileName)
    {
    m_program = glCreateProgram();
    //vertex shader
    m_shaders[0] = CreateShader(LoadShader(fileName + ".vs"), GL_VERTEX_SHADER); 
    m_shaders[0] = CreateShader(LoadShader(fileName + ".fs"),       
            GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); 

    
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++)
        glAttachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);

    
    glBindAttribLocation(m_program, 0, "position");

    
    glLinkProgram(m_program);
    CheckShaderError(m_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, true, "Error: Program linking failed. ");

    glValidateProgram(m_program);
    CheckShaderError(m_program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, true, "Error: Program is invalid. ");
}
//-----------
Shader::~Shader(void)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_SHADERS; i++)
    {
        glDetachShader(m_program, m_shaders[i]);
        glDeleteShader(m_shaders[i]);
    }

    glDeleteProgram(m_program);

}
//----------
void Shader::Bind()
{
    glUseProgram(m_program);
}
static GLuint CreateShader(const std::string & text, GLenum shaderType)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if(shader == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Shader creation failed! " << std::endl;
    }
    const GLchar* ShaderSourceStrings[1];
    GLint ShaderSourceStringsLengths[1];
    ShaderSourceStrings[0] = text.c_str();
    ShaderSourceStringsLengths[0] = text.length();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, ShaderSourceStrings, ShaderSourceStringsLengths);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    CheckShaderError(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, false, "Error: Shader compilation failed");
    return shader;
}
//-----------
static std::string LoadShader(const std::string & fileName)
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open((fileName).c_str());
    std::string output;
    std::string line;
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        while(file.good())
        {
            getline(file, line);
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "unable to load shader file: " << fileName << std::endl;
    }
    return output;
}
//-----------
static void CheckShaderError(GLuint shader, GLuint flag, bool isProgram, const std::string & errorMessage)
{
    GLint success = 0;
    GLchar error[1024] = {0};
    if(isProgram)
        glGetProgramiv(shader, flag, &success);
    else
        glGetShaderiv(shader, flag, &success);
    if(success == GL_FALSE)
    {
        if(isProgram){
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(error), NULL, error);
        std::cout << "error from program" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, sizeof(error), NULL, error);
            std::cout << "error from shader" << std::endl;
        }
            std::cerr << errorMessage << ": '"  << error << "'" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't mix `in/out` and `attribute/varying`. These are similar things but in different versions of GLSL/OpenGL.

Comment: Either version 120 and `attribute/varying`, or version 150+ and `in/out`.

Comment: @BDL: I think you can mix them, since `attribute / varying` are merely deprecated.  Depending on the version they may only be available in compatibility profile.

Comment: Also make sure that you're getting the results of `glGetShaderInfoLog` and `glGetProgramInfoLog` in debug versions of your code.

Comment: "*but is linked without a vertex shader*" Then your C++ code is to blame. You're not building your program correctly.

Comment: @DietrichEpp @NicolBolas I am, `glGetProgramInfoLog` is the one giving me this error. Again if i dont send anything from shader to shader, the code works fine. plus i was following a tutorial.

Comment: @user7437896: Sounds like a problem in the shader loading code, then.  I've updated the answer.  If that helps, great, but if it doesn't then you should be posting your shader loading code.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The shader code looks fine compared to what you uploaded, all steps are there. but ill post it anyway.

Comment: @user7437896: All the steps are there, but there's a mistake… obvious once you see it, even if you don't know OpenGL, but it's easy to miss.

Comment: @DietrichEpp oh my god, so silly :p, it worked, thanks a lot for your time

Comment: As a minor note, you can call `glDeleteShader` in the constructor instead of the destructor.  This way, you only need to call `glDeleteProgram` in the destructor.  The shaders are only needed for linking the program, you don't need to keep them around.

Comment: @DietrichEpp thanks for the tip, ill do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the error.

```
m_shaders[0] = 
m_shaders[0] =
```

---

> Fragment Shader contains a user varying but is linked without a vertex shader.

Linked without a vertex shader?  That would definitely cause problems.  The code should look something *vaguely* like this:

```
GLuint load_shader(GLenum shader_type, ...) {
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shader_type);
    ... load shader source code ...
    glCompileShader(shader);
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        // boom
    }
    ... glGetShaderInfoLog ...
    return shader;
}

GLuint load_program(...) {
    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    // Attach both fragment and vertex shader
    glAttachShader(prog, load_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, ...));
    glAttachShader(prog, load_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, ...));
    // Then link them together
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    GLint success;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        // boom
    }
    ... glGetProgramInfoLog ...
}
```

It's a fair bit of boilerplate code, and there are a lot of opportunities for the code to contain errors, so it's common for something to be wrong, especially since practically everything in OpenGL is just `typedef int GLxxx;` or something like that.

---

In GLSL 120, `in` and `out` are not storage qualifiers.  Use `varying` instead.

```
// Same in vertex and fragment shader.
varying vec4 ourColor;
```

Alternatively, use a newer GLSL version.

```
#version 330
out vec4 ourColor;
in vec3 position;

#version 330
in vec4 ourColor;
out vec4 fragColor;
```

Comment: i said in the question that i already tried using varying (instead of in and out), also changing the version didn't work :/ its weird i have tried everything

Comment: Why don't you update the question with your `varying` version of the shaders, instead of the ones you have now which clearly can't work because of the keyword / version mismatch.